# Parse: upload PHP files

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am new to using Parse and am developing an app using it as a backend. I want to also use it to develop a portal that would access data submitted from the mobile app.

Can I use Parse Cloud Code to upload my PHP files there (developed using PHP SDK)? Or should I upload it to another hosting provider and connect to Parse?

In the docs, it states I can use javascript library there but didn't catch anything about PHP SDK files uploaded and accessed from there.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, Cloud Code only supports JavaScript. If you want to use PHP for server-side logic (beforeSave triggers for example), look into using Webhooks which will hit an endpoint on a server specified by you (see https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced-cloud-code-webhooks)

If you are looking into hosting some sort of frontend on Parse (for example an admin area) then your only option is JavaScript, see https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#hosting

Comment: Thanks for the answer